# When will two free bodies under gravitational force meet?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Suppose that we have two bodies with masses $m1$, $m2$ large enough to cause significant gravitational force, at an initial distance $l$. Each exerts opposite force to the other with equal magnitude ($\vec{F_{12}}, \vec{F_{21}}$). Let $x_1(t), x_2(t)$ denote the position of each body, with inital conditions $x_{1_0}=0$ and $x_{2_0}=l$. The question is to express position as a function of time, in order to predict when they'll meet (obviously they need to occupy some space). By Newton's second law, we know that
\begin{equation}
F=ma\Rightarrow \frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{F(t)}{m}
\end{equation}
Thus, for each body: $\frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2}=\frac{F_{12}}{m_1}$, $\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2}=\frac{F_{21}}{m_2}$ 
We also know that the distance $d=x_2(t)-x_1(t)$. According to the universal law of gravitation
\begin{equation}
F_{12}(t)=F_{21}(t)=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{(x_2(t)-x_1(t))^2}
\end{equation}
Combining the above formulas, we get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2x_1(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{Gm_2}{(x_2(t)-x_1(t))^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2x_2(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{Gm_1}{(x_2(t)-x_1(t))^2}
\end{equation}
This seems to be a system of non linear ordinary differential equations, which neither I nor Wolfram Alpha have any idea how to solve. Any help is appreciated. I have a feeling that it's much easier if I use energies and Lagrangians but I'm not very familiar with Lagrangians...

Comment: It would probably be easier to work in a coordinate system that just describes the distance between them, that is a single variable $r(t)$ with the condition that they meet being the distance between their centers when their surfaces are in contact.

Comment: This question has been posed here many times. Just search for it.

Comment: @Triatticus I did what you recommended and the diff eq is $r''=\frac{a}{r^2}$ where $a=G(m_1-m_2)$. However the solution is this massive thing: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%28t%29%27%27%3Da%2Fy%5E2

Comment: Hint: falling is an orbit. Kepler laws apply.